# Use Gauss' Test to prove 1/n diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hey so I have to use Gauss' test to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges. I was able to do it pretty easily for the sum of $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$, but this one is giving me trouble. Here's where I'm at so far:

$$
\dfrac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} = 1+\dfrac{C}{n}+\dfrac{f(n)}{n^r} 
$$
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{n+1}}=\dfrac{n+1}{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{n}
$$
$$
1+\dfrac{1}{n}=1+\dfrac{C}{n}+\dfrac{f(n)}{n^r}\implies \dfrac{1-C}{n}=\dfrac{f(n)}{n^r}
$$

and this is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to say that $f(n)=0  \forall n>1$, because I think that would get me to the end otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: You can say $f(n)=0$.  Indeed, Gauss' test concludes divergence since $C=1$.

Comment: "I was able to do it pretty easily for the sum of $\frac1{n^{\hspace{.03 in}2}}$" ​ is a problem, since ​ $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2}$ ​ $\textbf{con}$verges. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I meant prove that 1/n^2 converges oops

Comment: Yet I fear that the fact that $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges is somehow accepted knowledge for the settlement of Gauss test. But ok, it's an exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears [in this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html) and using your work partially, Gauss' test tells us that since

$$\frac{\frac1n}{\frac1{n+1}}=1+\frac1n=1+\frac hn+\frac{B(n)}{n^{119}}$$

with $\;B(n):=0\;$ a bounded function of $\;n\;$ as $\;n\to\infty\;$ , then since $\;h=1\le1\;$ ,  the corresponding series diverges.